# How do you force Swift setter to trigger on initial value?

Tags: swift, swiftui, setter

In the DecimalAmount function I can't get it to display the initial value of the amount. It shows 0.00 as the initial display even though the actual value is 22.22. Anyone know how to get around this issue?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View
{
    @State var amount: Decimal = 22.22
    
    var body: some View
    {
        DecimalAmount(prompt: "Enter Value", value: $amount)
            .padding()
    }
}

struct DecimalAmount: View
{
    @State var prompt = ""
    @Binding var value: Decimal
    
    var body: some View
    {
        // How to get this to show the initial value of 22.22
        TextField(prompt, text: Binding(get: { value.decimal }, set: { value = Decimal(string: $0) ?? 0.0 }))
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
    }
}

extension Decimal
{
    var decimal: String
    {
        return String(format: "%3.2f", self as NSDecimalNumber)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think uou just need to give you value an initial amount, like `@Binding var value = Decimal(string: "22.22")`. Unrelated, but important: Generally avoid ` String(format:)`, and definitely don't use it for generating text that you'll show to the user. `String(format: "%3.2f", ...)` will produce text that is incorrect formatted for many users around the world (e.g. some places group digits differently, use comma for decimal separation instead of spaces, use spaces for digit grouping instead of commas, etc.). Use a `NumberFormatter` to do it properly.

Comment: It has a value assigned in ContentView before DecimalAmount is first called.

Comment: Oh, your `Prompt` is also an issue. Any non-numerical input (including the initial value, `""`) will make you hit the `?? 0.0` case, so that's what you're seeing.

Comment: The prompt is what shows up when the field is blank, but to be sure, I changed it to 7.0 and changed the 0.0 to 5.0 but still show 0.00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another init that has a `value:` argument so that you can use the Binding directly and also can be formatted directly using a supplied format

```
TextField("",
          value: $value,
          format: .number.precision(.fractionLength(2)))
```

This init also has a `prompt:` argument and it works fine both with and without it. [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/init(_:value:format:prompt:)-7flsn)